# How to make changes on an image that is being processed after using optical character recognition using python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, ocr

I have decided to use OCR to search for printed text in my black and white image. If I were to find this text in the image and then replace it with something else, how would I go about writing a python script for this?

For example, I have a black and white image where I have detected the a block of text. I would like to know if its possible to replace the letters that I have detected with some other letters?

Comment: It is possible, but *how* would depend greatly on what tools you are currently using. Be more specific, and post and explain the code you already have.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge. I am fairly new to both python scripting as well as image processing. My idea was to use something like Tesseract OCR for just the detection of the text. My understanding is that I could create a GIMP plug-in which could either remove or replace this text. Unfortunately I have no relevant code to show, this is just a basic idea.

Comment: Until you have a more specific question, the only answer you are going to be able to get is "Yes, it is possible". You would have to look into building GIMP plugins first though. I suggest you do that, and then return back here and post new questions as soon as you have some specific problems. Good luck!

Comment: GIMP plug-ins are not the problem here - of course one could use one -  but it is hard - your first task is to read about image processing and OCR -  - even though you won't be coding the OCR part - you have to understand aspects of pre-processing, imaging segmentation  - and such - then you will be able to imagine where on the chain of tens of ops needed for the OCR part you can plug code to get some feedback from the OCRing, and insert new parts on the image

Comment: I would not say it is a task for a single developer - but if it can be done, it should tak eyou the better part of 2 years of hardwork. Not likely you will get a complete answer bellow.

Comment: "it should take you the better part of 2 years of hardwork" - I disagree.  I can implement this production-worthy process in a couple of days.  It depends on the tools used vs. writing routines on your own, and of course on the complexity and consistency of specs in the OP's project.